# CakePHP 3 Query builder order by nested relations

Tags: cakephp, orm, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

The documentation for order function is not good enough. This is what I have:

Table A   <---- MiddleTableAB ---->  Table B  <--- MiddleTableBC ---> Table C

So I have a Table B that has a many to many relationship with Table A and also has a many to many relationship with table C.

What I need is a list of items of Table B. They need to be grouped by Table A's ID and then by Table C's ID.

This is what I have inside the Table B function:

```
    $query=$this->find();
    $query->contain([
        'MiddleTableAB.TableA'=> function ($q) {
                return $q->select(['id','name']);
            },
        'MiddleTableBC.TableC'=> [
            'strategy' => 'select',
            'queryBuilder' => function ($q) {
                    return $q->select(['id','name']);
            },
        ]
    ]);
    //$query->select(['id','description']);
    $query->group(['TableA.id','TableC.id']);
    $data = $query->all();
```

But cake says there is no TableA.id.
If I delete the group call, I get all the data that I need to build the result needed. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I apologize as i overlooked at the Cakephp Version Number (that is 3) in the question. Please find my edits as follows :

For Multiple joins in Cakephp 3, please check docs [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-joins)

Check this example code:

```html
$query = $countries->find()
        ->hydrate(false)
        ->join([
            'City' => [
                'table' => 'cities',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => 'Country.id = City.country_id'
            ],
            'Address' => [
                'table' => 'addresses',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => 'City.id = Address.city_id'
            ]
        ])
        ->order(['state' => 'DESC']);
```

In the above, The hydratate method tells the ORM not to try generating entities (Check [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#disabling-hydration)). If you want the entities to be generated try removing that part.

Comment: This code is valid for cakephp 2 not cakephp 3. Also this example dosen't use order function. Can you please help me in my specific problem? thank you

Comment: I am sorry for over looking for Version number. I modified the answer accordingly, check is it fits your needs (Order function is just another nesting to the find, i added it to the answer)